# Is there some HTML complete page editor (JQuery, Silverlight, ...)?

Tags: jquery, html, silverlight, templates, editor

Is there some existing JQuery or Silverlight solution that allows you to create complete HTML page from scratch (visually like in Dreamweaver)?

So, we are not looking for standard HTML WYSIWYG editors where you have above textarea bold, italic, link icons, alignment..., but we need something like this:

- User get initial page layout when he choose predefined HTML template (he see some empty containers with borders - they will render at the end to DIVs)
- When initial layout is loaded in viewable container user can scale these containers and move them also (dragging). He can also delete some container or add new one
- When one containter is clicked user can choose which content will be loaded there (image, video, rich html,...) and then editor for this content is shown and after user finish editing whole content is displayed like it is

If there is no cool solution, does anybody want to collaborate with us on making this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a web-based CMS (Content Management System) with embedded HTML editors.

Examples:

- [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)
- [SiteFinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/)
- [Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/)

Comment: No, we are not looking for PHP or any other CMS, we just need that control that will produce created HTML as output

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like http://www.online-html-editor.org/ and http://ckeditor.com/demo?

Comment: Thanks, according to the links: 
We are not looking for WYSIWYG editors like CKEditor.
Second solution (online HTML editor) is something that we are looking for (in basics) - didn't see that it allows scaling, removing, moving editable boxes (containers) - we will look a little bit more

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for tinyMCE http://www.tinyMCE.com

Comment: No, but such editor can be used to edit one container region if we choose that this region will have rich text. If we decide that this container (region) will have image inside then we will give user some custom editor.

Point is that these Word like editors are not user friendly (they are develope friendly) and when it comes to tables (to get more complex layout) is not to user friendly to complete what you wanted.